# How can I match an entire regex only if one of its segments matches?

Tags: regex, json

For example, I want to match the _msg object here:

```
{"message":{"_id":"","_obj":"","_obj_type":"1","_type":"ERROR","_msg":"An error has occurred!","_user":"","_added":"","_func":"Document Uploaded","_action":""}, "data":[]}
```

but not here:

```
{"message":{"_id":"","_obj":"","_obj_type":"1","_type":"ERROR","_msg":"","_user":"","_added":"","_func":"Document Uploaded","_action":""}, "data":[]}
```

Because there is an actual message to display. This is my attempted regex:

```
"_msg"\:"([^"]*){1,}"
```

However, it still matches even an empty _msg, which I do not want. Am I even close? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just parse the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easier to use a JSON parser, but the `*` means (zero or more).  Use `+` (one or more).

```
"_msg":"([^"]+)"
```

Yes empty string matches `(anything)*{1,}`

Comment: Fantastic, that worked! Thank you, I'm still relatively new to regex so I still get stumped sometimes.